# Como funciona essa função?

Tags: c, funções, recursão

Faz parte de um algoritmo de ordenação, lendo o código ficou parecendo pra mim que o a função nunca faz a chamada: `sort(mid+1, high)`; fica em *loop* na primeira `sort(low, mid)`; até sair do `if`, e esse `return` também não entendi pra que serve.

```
void sort(int low, int high) {
   int mid;

   if(low < high) {

      mid = (low + high) / 2;

      sort(low, mid);
      sort(mid+1, high);
      merging(low, mid, high);
   } else { 
      return;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Explique melhor a sua dúvida

Comment: seria bom você acertar a indentação do código para facilitar o entendimento do mesmo...coloque 4 espaços no início de cada linha

Comment: Aqui você encontra a explicação deste método de ordenação: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort ou sua dúvida é sobre o funcionamento de funções recursivas?

Comment: Faz parte de um algoritmo de ordenação, lendo o codigo ficou parecendo pra mim que o a função nunca faz a chamada: sort(mid+1, high); fica em loop na primeira sort(low, mid); até sair do if, e esse return também não entendi pra que serve.

Comment: É o algoritmo de implementação do merge sort.

Comment: @Vitor A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Você tem aí uma função recursiva. É necessário em algum lugar sair da função certo? E precisa ser condicional porque como esta função é chamada por ela mesma vai executando repetidas vezes item por item, em algum momento não deve continuar chamando a si própria e precisa sair, então se `low` não for menor que `high` a função nada executa (note que esta última chamada serve só para forçar a saída, não tem execução) e encerra acabando a repetição de novas chamadas e voltando para a chamada anterior que continuará executando o resto do código, portanto pode ainda executar mais vezes outras partes do código ou pode começar descer a pilha de execução.

Parece que a dúvida está só neste ponto porque sabendo que em algum momento a execução não ocorre e há um retorno sem fazer nada dá pra perceber que uma hora a chama volta ter controle da execução e sai do que será esse laço de repetição recursiva que parece infinito (e seria mesmo se não tivesse esse `return`). Quando sair da primeira execução da função `sort()` ela vai iniciar a segunda, que em algum momento vai terminar também e aí executará a `mergeing()` e até que encerrá e voltará para quem chamou, que possivelmente será ela mesma, até que vai descendo o nível até chegar na primeira chamada da função.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante!

Comment: @Vitor veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.